# chartSeries grey lines

Tags: r, charts, quantmod

I am using the chartSeries function from the quantmod package, and the theme I am using is white.mono. The chart is pretty clean, but I want to remove the horizontal grey lines that intersect the y axis.

Anybody know how to turn these off? Also, is it possible to turn off the last price that is displayed in the top left corner? Here are my plot parameters:

```
chartSeries(finalData[,1:4],
     name="GCQ4 Comdty: GOLD 100 OZ FUTR Aug14",
     theme=chartTheme('white.mono'),
     type="bars",
     bar.type='ohlc',
     major.ticks='months',
     show.grid=FALSE,
     log.scale=TRUE)

addLines(h=1388.10,col='red')
addLines(h=1240.20,col='blue')
```

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove the grid  you should set the `grid.col` to `NA` :

```
tt <- chartTheme('white.mono')
tt$grid.col <- NA
chartSeries(finalData[,1:4],
 name="GCQ4 Comdty: GOLD 100 OZ FUTR Aug14",
 theme=tt,...)
```

Comment: Or just use `chartTheme('white.mono', grid.col=NA)`

Comment: thanks josh! do you know how to turn off the last price, displayed in the top left?